# RejectExecutionError while running async tasks in a loop

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am using following code

```
private void getOnlineConnections()
{       
    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.size(); i++)
    {
        final Persons person =  contacts.get(i);
        String queryString = null;
        try {
            queryString = String.format(Constants.GET_ONLINE_URL, 
                                URLEncoder.encode(person.myId, "UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ResponseCallback callback = new ResponseCallback() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response) 
            {
                response = response.trim();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(String exception) 
            {}
        };

        new MyAsyncTask(queryString, callback); 
    }       
}
```

MyAsyncTask is an AsyncTask.

Now the number of contacts can be more than 128 or more than limit of TheadPoolExecutor.

How can Increase this limit so I won't get crash on `RejectExecutionError`.

Comment: Instead of creating a new `AsyncTask` for each contact, divide the whole group of contacts into buckets and make every `AsyncTask` process a bucket of contacts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using API Level 11 or higher, create your own thread pool and use `executeOnExecutor()`.

If you are supporting older devices, don't use `AsyncTask`. Create your own thread pool and use other means (e.g., `runOnUiThread()`) to arrange for work to be done on the main application thread.

Comment: I have added runOnUiThread(new MyRunnable(queryString, callback)); instead of myAsyncTask and replaced AsyncTask with Runnable. But this is causing my screen to go blank until it gets all data. I want to run all this in background. Any ideas?

Comment: @MuhammadUmar: You cannot replace `AsyncTask` with `Runnable`. `Runnable` does not run on a background thread by default.

Comment: I had the idea, make an async task and call all runonUIthread in it thus running them in background. However Now i am changing server, instead of many so much queries. I am trying to use service and using better query on server side. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is something that sounds more like a thread than a task-  I'd start off a thread and just have it chug through those contacts one at a time in the background. You can even partition the dataset into multiple chunks and create 1 thread per chunk if you want it to process in parallel (although unless the linux scheduler assigns those threads to different cores you won't actually achieve a speedup this way, so I'm not sure I'd bother unless its absolutely needed, and then I'd measure to make sure it worked).